Angular Material drag&drop stacked deck of cards and auto expand on hover
How can I achieve the following behaviour using Angular Material and Drag&Drop functionalities? I want to be able to see the cards fully expanded on mouse over, so the other cards below just move down their absolute margin-tops, and still be able to rearrange them using drag&drop cdk.
Those are a couple of examples from a website that offers this functionality. I was wondering if it can be done with Angular and Material.


I was able to stack them by using position: absolute and margin-top: calc(35% * (var(--index))); them but still don't know how to make the one hovered full height while pushing the others below down.
Also, my solution seems to be a bit clumsy as it recalculates the margin a lot when there is a drag movement, you can see how it "jumps" or "staggers" a lot. That would be another problem, though.
This is my example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/gabkl9-zywnff?file=src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.css
Thanks in advance.

We can use the general sibling selector (~) to offset the other cards, below a height, here 130px, this will give the desired result!
.example-box:hover ~ div.example-box {
  margin-top: calc((35% * (var(--index))) + 130px);
}

full css
.example-list {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.example-box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: move;
  background: white;
  margin-top: calc(35% * (var(--index)));
}

.example-box:hover ~ div.example-box {
  margin-top: calc((35% * (var(--index))) + 130px);
}

.cdk-drag-preview {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cdk-drag-animating {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.example-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .example-box:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you, didn't think about the sibling selector for this purpose. Now is working perfect as expected!
